# Customize Codeigniter's "the URI you submitted has disallowed characters"

Tags: codeigniter, uri

I'm new to CI, wanna ask some questions about CI's "URI... disallowed characters" page. I know CI made it for security reasons, and I like it. But I don't like my website visitor seeing that when they input those disallowed chars. Can I change the page looks like my customized 404 page? 
Yes, I have modified the URI file, but I can't call any controller because the file is outside the application folder.

Thanks. Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more info about why you can't call any controller because the file is outside the app folder? What file do you mean?

To begin, I would recommend sending the values via POST to avoid problems with the characters allowed in the URL.

Also, but it is not recommended, you can disable the characters not allowed in the config.php file, in $config['permitted_uri_chars']